# За что отвечают параметры?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Подскажите, за что отвечает каждый из параметров  `<GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,0 L1,0 1,0.1, 0,0.1Z" />`.

Задача состоит в том, что бы нарисовать милиметровку на заднем фоне `Canvasa`. Я делаю это так:

```
<DrawingBrush x:Key="gridBackgroundBrush" 
        Viewport="0,0,10,10" 
        ViewportUnits="Absolute"
        TileMode="Tile">
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <DrawingGroup.Children>
                        <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,0 L1,0 1,0.1, 0,0.1Z" Brush="Green" />
                        <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,0 L0,1 0.1,1, 0.1,0Z" Brush="Green" />
                    </DrawingGroup.Children>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
```

Как мне получить что-то подобное к [этому](http://www.rnceus.com/ekg/ekghowto.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это называется [разметка пути](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms752293.aspx)

```
Как мне получить что-то подобное к этому?
```

Может поможет [вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9437270/1503829) от зарубежных друзей?

Comment: Спасибо! Очень полезные ссылки!